# Corruped git object file

Tags: git, github

Got fatal error when using

'''
git pull
'''
to pull the remote changes to local.

error: unable to read sha1 file of /estimation.py (cccc0dc45db57d5fe61e51f224b4cf86c19cf4cc)

I tried to remove the file "estimation " in github remote. The error is the same.
However, when I can do tried to revert the commit of removing "estimation.py". The following error shows up

error: unable to read sha1 file of Mov_track/single_agent/highway-env/highway_env/vehicle/uncertainty/estimation.py (cccc0dc45db57d5fe61e51f224b4cf86c19cf4cc)
fatal: revert failed

How should I solve this problem in this situation.

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour if you work in a fresh clone? I'm wondering whether it's your local sandbox that has some corruption or the remote itself, so trying to reproduce the problem in a fresh clone might answer that.

Comment: If a fresh clone displays the same error message for that object file : check the output of `git fsck`